# Reset form from parent component

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, parent-child, angular-forms

I have one component under which I have modal popup which contains child component :

```
<modal data-backdrop="static" #modalTask (onDismiss)="modalTask.close()" [size]="'lg'">
    <modal-header>
        <h4 style="color:#fff">Add CRL Task</h4>
    </modal-header>
    <modal-body>
        <TaskComponent [isReset] ="resetForm" #tasks></crlTask>
    </modal-body>
    <modal-footer>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onTaskClick();">Create</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modalTask.close();">Cancel</button>
    </modal-footer>
</modal>
```

Now that child component is as follows :

```
<form #taskForm="ngForm" name="rplForm">
 //Contains Input Controls 
</form>
```

**EDIT**

As got one solution I have put reset inside `ngOnChanges` of child component. Here is the code from Child component

```
taskForm: FormGroup;
@Input() isReset: boolean = false;

ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.isReset) {
              this.rplForm.reset();
        }
    }
```

Now I am saving `taskForm` on `onTaskClick()` and I am able to do so. What I am not able to do is to resetting the form which is under child component.

I tried using `reset()` but was not able to do so. Anything using which I can do so from parent component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the update you have provided with `ngOnChanges` is that you need to use the `NgForm` directive as you are using a template driven form. `rplForm` is **not** a `FormGroup`, you don't even need it here, as that belongs with reactive forms. So what you want to reference is `taskForm` and reset that. `rplForm` is redundant here.

You need to import `ViewChild` to be able to reference your form, then call `reset` on your form:

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

//...

@ViewChild('taskForm') myForm: NgForm;

ngOnChanges() {
  if (this.isReset) {
     this.myForm.reset();
  }
}
```

Comment: `rplForm` is `taskForm`. That was a mistake that I have updated.

Comment: Although I tried it yesterday it was not working, But somehow started working today. Maybe I was doing something wrong. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Maybe some magic happened over night :D Well, but glad to hear you got it working :)

Comment: Seems like that so. :D

Answer (score 0):

create subject and pass change event into parent component and listen into child component 
for example:

// create one service for that and write this code

```
 onFormReset = new Subject<void>();

   resetForm(): void {
     this.onFormReset.next();
   }
```

// component

```
reset(): void{
   this.service.resetForm();
}
```

**Note. Inject your service into component constructor**

// parent component html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="reset();">Reset</button>
```

Child component

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
this.service.onFormReset.subscribe(()=>{
   reset your form here
);
}
```

Comment: Other than using services?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use input as follow:

Your parent component typescript file:

```
private resetForm:boolean = false;
```

Your parent component html file:

```
<modal data-backdrop="static" #modalTask (onDismiss)="modalTask.close()" [size]="'lg'">
<modal-header>
    <h4 style="color:#fff">Add CRL Task</h4>
</modal-header>
<modal-body>
    <TaskComponent #tasks [reset]="resetForm"></crlTask>
</modal-body>
<modal-footer>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onTaskClick();">Create</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="modalTask.close();">Cancel</button>
</modal-footer>
```

Your child component typescript:

```
import {Input, OnChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Input() reset:boolean = false;


ngOnChanges(){
   if(this.reset){
       //Here you can reset your form
   }
}
```

**Edit**

```
 <form #taskForm="ngForm" name="rplForm" [formGroup]="rplForm">
   //Contains Input Controls 
 </form>
```

Comment: Not happening. Tried it

Comment: Strange, did you implement OnChanges on your child component ?

Comment: I did check it and it goes inside the `ngOnChanges` as well but still not happening

Comment: Could you apply the inside the ngOnChanges please

Comment: Updated the question please check

Comment: Yes I am using reactive form

Answer (score 0):

in the HTML page

```
 <child
   #ngRefInput
   (onInputChange)="onChange($event)"
    [config]="otpConfig">
 </child>
```

In the TS file

```
onChange{
this.ngRefInput.yourForm.reset();
}
```